# Trying to get my java menu via methods to count properly

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods, count

I am new to java, and have gotten THIS far with this simple menu program, getting the other parts to work(hence why I added them) but I am wondering exactly what I am doing wrong? I have tried debugging, but I am just so inexperienced that I don't really understand WHAT to do. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I have figured most of this out on my own, just certain parts don't work, and I have kind of hit a wall.

1) Report #6 (reserve_info) – Specific reservation information – prompt the user for the reservation code, search the reservation arrays and print the information on that reservation, then also print the flight information from the flight arrays for that specific reservation (READ COMMENTS)

2)Report #7 (all_flights) – Summary of all flights – first print the flight information for one flight from the flight arrays, then go to the reservation arrays and print all reservations for that flight.  Then go on to the next flight etc… (READ COMMENTS)

3)Report #9 (exit_program) - This method will write all data from the two sets of parallel arrays back to the flightsx.dat and the reservationx.dat files.  Therefore, if the user entered new data or deleted data, the current arrays would be over-written back to the data files.  Then, the next time the program would run, that new data would be read in.

```
          package PhaseIII;

          import java.io.BufferedReader;
          import java.io.FileReader;
          import java.io.IOException;
          import java.util.StringTokenizer;

          import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

          public class PhaseIII {

      /**
      * @param args
      */
      public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       array_info data= new array_info();
       int selection;

       selection = data.menu();

       //call start_program & start_program1  
       //DO WHILE LOOP    
        while(selection!=4)
       {
       if (selection == 1)
        {
          //put call to Modify_flight
         data.flight_report();
        }
         else if (selection == 2)
         {
           //put call to Modify_reservation
          data.modify_reservation();
           }
            else if (selection == 3)
           {
           //put call to Report
                data.report();
           }
        selection =data.menu();
         }//END WHILE LOOP
     //call exit_program   
     data.exit_program();
     System.exit(0);
     }//end main method
           }


       class array_info
       {
   int count=-1,i;
   int rcount=-1;
   String [] flight = new String [100];
   int    [] flight_number = new int [100];
   String [] origin = new String [100];
   String [] destination = new String [100];
   String [] date = new String [100];
   String [] time = new String [100];

   int    [] fl_number = new int [100];
   int    [] reservation_code = new int [100];
   String [] last_name = new String [100];
   String [] first_name = new String [100];
   String [] seat_type = new String [100];
   double [] seat_cost = new double [100];{

   count=start_program();
   rcount=start_program1();{
   }
   }

         int menu()
         {
           String mnumber;
           int number;
           String output = "ACME AIRLINE SYSTEM" + " \n " + " \n " +
               "1. ADD/MODIFY FLIGHT INFORMATION" + " \n " +
               "2. ADD/MODIFY RESERVATION INFORMATION" + " \n " +
               "3. REPORT SECTION" + " \n " +
               "4. EXIT AIRLINE SYSTEM" + " \n" + " \n " +
               "Please make your selection  >";
                mnumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, output, " ",
                                                 JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
           number=Integer.parseInt(mnumber);
           return number;
    }//method menu

         int modify_flight()
          {
               String mnumber2;
               int number2;
               String output = "Modify Flight Information Menu" + " \n " + " \n " +
                   "1. ADD FLIGHT" + " \n " +
                   "2. DELETE FLIGHT" + " \n " +
                   "3. MODIFY FLIGHT" + " \n " +
                   "4. EXIT THIS MENU" + " \n" + " \n " +
                   "Please make your selection  >";
                    mnumber2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, output, " ",
                                                     JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
               number2=Integer.parseInt(mnumber2);
               return number2;    
         }//method modify_flight

         int reportmenu()
         {
             String mnumber3;
               int number3;
               String output = "ACME AIRLINES" + " \n " +
                   "1. All Flight Info" + " \n " +
                   "2. All Reservation Info" + " \n " +
                   "3. Value of Reservations of a specific type" + " \n " +
                   "4. All Reservations of a specific flight" + " \n" + 
                   " 5. All Flights from a specific city" + " \n" +
                   " 6. Specific Reservation Information" + " \n" +
                   " 7. Summary of all flights" + " \n" +
                   " 8. All Flights to a specific city" + " \n" +
                   " 9. Exit Report Menu" + " \n" +
                   " Please make your selection  >";
                    mnumber3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, output, " ",
                                                     JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
               number3=Integer.parseInt(mnumber3);
               return number3; 
         }//method report_menu

         int start_program()
         {
                String newLine;
                  try
                  {
                    //define a file valuable for Buffered read
                     BufferedReader Flights_file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("flightsx.dat"));
                     //read lines in file until there are no more lines in the file to read
                     while ((newLine = Flights_file.readLine()) != null)
                       {
                         //there is a "#" between each data item in each line
                          StringTokenizer delimiter = new StringTokenizer(newLine,"#");
                          count=count+1;
                          flight[count] =delimiter.nextToken();
                          flight_number[count] = Integer.parseInt(delimiter.nextToken());
                          origin[count] =delimiter.nextToken();
                          destination[count] =delimiter.nextToken();
                          date[count] =delimiter.nextToken();
                          time[count] =delimiter.nextToken();
                       }//while loop
                       Flights_file.close();
                    }//end try
                catch (IOException error)
                  {
                  //there was an error on the file writing
                  System.out.println("Error on file read " + error);
                  }//error on read
                return count;
          }//end start_program

         int start_program1()
         {
                        String newLine;
                          try
                          {
                            //define a file valuable for Buffered read
                             BufferedReader Reservation_file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("reservationx.dat"));
                             //read lines in file until there are no more lines in the file to read
                             while ((newLine = Reservation_file.readLine()) != null)
                               {
                                 //there is a "#" between each data item in each line
                                  StringTokenizer delimiter = new StringTokenizer(newLine,"#");
                                  rcount=rcount+1;
                                  reservation_code[rcount] = Integer.parseInt(delimiter.nextToken());
                                  fl_number[rcount] = Integer.parseInt(delimiter.nextToken());
                                  last_name[rcount] =delimiter.nextToken();
                                  first_name[rcount] =delimiter.nextToken();
                                  seat_type[rcount] =delimiter.nextToken();
                                  seat_cost[rcount] = Double.parseDouble(delimiter.nextToken());
                                }//while loop
                               Reservation_file.close();
                            }//end try
                        catch (IOException error)
                          {
                          //there was an error on the file writing
                          System.out.println("Error on file read " + error);
                          }//error on read
                        return rcount;
        }//end start_program1   

         void flight_report()
         {
            // DECLARED VARIABLES]
               int selection2;
               selection2 =modify_flight();
            //DO WHILE LOOP    
                while(selection2!=4)
               {
               if (selection2 == 1)
                {
                  //put call to add flight
                   add_flight();
                }
               else if (selection2 == 2)
                {
                  //put call to delete flight
                   delete_flight();
                }
               else if (selection2 == 3)
                {
                  //put call to mod flight
                   mod_flight();
                }
               selection2 =modify_flight();
                 }//END WHILE LOOP
            }//method report

         int add_flight()
          {
            //add new flight information
                String svalue,Output;
                count=count+1;
                Output = "Enter the Flight Company";                    //string
                svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                          "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                Output = "Enter the Flight Number";                     //4 digit integer
                svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                          "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                flight_number[count] = Integer.parseInt(svalue);
                Output = "Enter the Flight City Origin";                //string
                svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                          "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                Output = "Enter the Flight City Destination";           //string
                svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                          "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                Output = "Enter the Flight Date";                       //string
                svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                          "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                Output = "Enter the Flight Time";                       //string
                svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                          "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                return count;
         }//method modify_flight

        void delete_flight()
        {
            String output, svalue;
            int position=0,i,modselect;
            output="Enter the Flight Number to delete ";
            svalue=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,output,
                "Input Data",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);;
            for(i=0;i<=count;++i)
            {
                if(flight_number.equals(output))
                    position =i;
            }
            for(i=position;i<=count-1;++i)
            {
                output=output+1;
            }
            count=count=1;
        }

        void mod_flight()
        {
            String output,svalue, value;
            int position=0,i,modselect;
            output="Enter the Flight Number to modify ";
            svalue=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,output,
                "Input Data",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);;
            for(i=0;i<=count;++i)
            {
                if(flight_number.equals(output))
                    position =-i;
            }
            output="";
            output=output+"1. Modify Flight Company "+"\n";
            output=output+"2. Modify City Origin "+"\n";
            output=output+"3. Modify City Destination "+"\n";
            output=output+"4. Modify Flight Date "+"\n";
            output=output+"5. Modify Flight Time "+"\n";
            output=output+" Please make your selection ";
            value=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,output,
                    "Input Data",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            modselect=Integer.parseInt(value);
            if(modselect ==1)
            {
                output = "Enter the Flight Company";
                svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,output,
                          "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            }
            else
                if(modselect==2)
                {
                    output = "Enter the Flight City Origin";
                    svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,output,
                              "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                }
                else
                    if(modselect==3)
                    {
                        output = "Enter the Flight City Destination";
                        svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,output,
                                  "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                    }
                    else
                        if(modselect==4)
                        {
                            output = "Enter the Flight Date";
                            svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,output,
                                      "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                        }
                        else
                            if(modselect==5)
                            {
                                output = "Enter the Flight Time";
                                svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,output,
                                          "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                            }
        } 

        int modify_reservation()
            {
                        //add new flight information
                            String svalue,Output;
                            rcount=rcount+1;
                            Output = "Enter the Reservation Code";                      //4 digit integer
                            svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                                      "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                            reservation_code[rcount] = Integer.parseInt(svalue);
                            Output = "Enter the Flight Number";                         //4 digit integer
                            svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                                      "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                            fl_number[rcount] = Integer.parseInt(svalue);
                            Output = "Enter the Last Name";                             //string
                            svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                                      "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                            Output = "Enter the First Name";                            //string
                            svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                                      "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                            Output = "Enter the Type of Seat";                          //string
                            svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                                      "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                            Output = "Enter the Cost of seat";                          //double
                            svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                                      "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                            seat_cost[rcount] = Double.parseDouble(svalue);
                            return rcount;
        }//method modify_reservation

         void report()
         {
            // DECLARED VARIABLES]
               int selection3;
               selection3 =reportmenu(); 
            //DO WHILE LOOP    
                while(selection3!=9)
               {
               if (selection3 == 1)
                {
                  //put call to All Flight Info
                  display_flight();
                }
               else if (selection3 == 2)
                {
                  //put call to All Reservation Info
                   display_reservation();
                }
               else if (selection3 == 3)
                {
                  //put call to Value of Reservations of a specific type
                   seat_value();
                }
               else if (selection3 == 4)
                {
                  //put call to All Reservations on a specific flight
                   print_flight();
                }
               else if (selection3 == 5)
                {
                  //put call to All flights from a specific city
                  city_origin();
                }
               else if (selection3 == 6)
                {
                  //put call to Specific reservation information 
                  reserve_info();
                }
               else if (selection3 == 7)
                {
                  //put call to Summary of all flights 
                   all_flights();
                }
               else if (selection3 == 8)
                {
                  //put call to All flights to a specific city 
                   city_destination();
                }
               selection3 =reportmenu();
                 }//END WHILE LOOP
         }//method report

         void display_flight()
         {
             int i;
             System.out.println("All flight Information:");
             for(i=0;i<=count;++i)
             {
                 System.out.println(flight[i]+" "+flight_number[i]+" "+origin[i]+" "+destination[i]+" "+date[i]+" "+time[i]);
             }
         }// method display_flight

         void display_reservation()
         {
             int i;
             System.out.println("All Reservations Information:");
             for(i=0;i<=rcount;++i)
             {
                 System.out.println(reservation_code[i]+" "+fl_number[i]+" "+last_name[i]+" "+first_name[i]+" "+seat_type[i]+" "+seat_cost[i]);
             }
         }// method display_reservation

         void seat_value()
            {
             int i;
             double total=0;
             String search_seat = "";
             String output = "Enter the Seat Type you are searching for";
             search_seat = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                                       output, " ",
                                                       JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
             for (i = 0; i <=rcount; ++i) {
                //CHECK IF coach, first, or business
                  if(seat_type[i].equals(search_seat))
                     {
                         total+=seat_cost[i];
                         System.out.println(reservation_code[i]+" "+fl_number[i]+" "+last_name[i]+" "+first_name[i]+" "+seat_type[i]+" "+seat_cost[i]);
                     }
             }
              System.out.println("The total for " +search_seat+ " = " +total);
            }// method seat_value

         void print_flight()
            {
             int i, total=0;

             String search_flight = "";
             String output = "Enter the Flight Number you are searching for";
             search_flight = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                                       output, " ",
                                                       JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

             for (i = 0; i <=rcount; ++i) {
                //CHECK flight number
                  int flight_number = Integer.parseInt(search_flight);
                  if(fl_number[i] == flight_number)

                     {
                         total+=fl_number[i];
                         System.out.println(reservation_code[i]+" "+fl_number[i]+" "+last_name[i]+" "+first_name[i]+" "+seat_type[i]+" "+seat_cost[i]);
                     }
             }
            }//method print_flight

         void city_origin()
            {
             int i, j;
             int match_count= 0;
             String search_city = "";
             String output = "Enter the City from a particular flight you are searching for";
             search_city = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                                       output, " ",
                                                       JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

             System.out.println(" All flights from "+search_city);
             for (i = 0; i <=count; ++i) {
                      if(origin[i].equals(search_city))
                         {
                             System.out.println(flight[i]+" "+flight_number[i]+" "+origin[i]+" "+destination[i]+" "+date[i]+" "+time[i]);
                            match_count=0;
             for (j = 0; j <=rcount; ++j) 
             {
                         if(flight_number[i] == fl_number[j])
                                               match_count=match_count+1;
                         }//j loop
                         System.out.println("The total reservations for " +flight_number[i]+ " = " +match_count);
                        }//if match
             }
             }//method city_origin

         void reserve_info()
         {
             int i, j;
             int match_count=0;
             String search_reservation = "";
             String output = "Enter the Reservation Code";
             search_reservation = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                                       output, " ",
                                                       JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

             for (i = 0; i <=rcount; ++i) {
                //CHECK reservation code
                  int r_code= Integer.parseInt(search_reservation);
                  if(reservation_code[i] == r_code) 
                     {
                         System.out.println(reservation_code[i]+" "+fl_number[i]+" "+last_name[i]+" "+first_name[i]+" "+seat_type[i]+" "+seat_cost[i]);
                         match_count=0;
             for (j = 0; j <=count; ++j)
             {
                 if(fl_number[i] == flight_number[j]);                      //print flight info from that fl_number
                                    match_count=match_count+1;
                    }//j loop
             System.out.println(flight[j]+" "+flight_number[j]+" "+origin[j]+" "+destination[j]+" "+date[j]+" "+time[j]);
                     }//if match
         } 
         }//method reserve_info

         void all_flights ()
         {
             int i;
             System.out.println("All flight Information:");
             for(i=0;i<=count;++i)
             {
                 System.out.println(flight[i]+" "+flight_number[i]+" "+origin[i]+" "+destination[i]+" "+date[i]+" "+time[i]);
             }// NEED TO CATEGORIZE ALL RESERVATIONS (FL_NUMBER) BENEATH EACH FLIGHT (FLIGHT_NUMBER)
         }//method all_flights

         void city_destination ()
         {
             int i, j;
             int match_count= 0;
             String search_destination= "";
             String output = "Enter the City to a particular flight you are searching for";
             search_destination= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                                       output, " ",
                                                       JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
             System.out.println(" All flights from "+search_destination);
             for (i = 0; i <=count; ++i) 
             {
                      if(destination[i].equals(search_destination))
                         {
                             System.out.println(flight[i]+" "+flight_number[i]+" "+origin[i]+" "+destination[i]+" "+date[i]+" "+time[i]);
                            match_count=0;
             for (j = 0; j <=rcount; ++j) 
             {
                         if(flight_number[i] == fl_number[j])
                                               match_count=match_count+1;
                         }//j loop
                         System.out.println("The total reservations for " +flight_number[i]+ " = " +match_count);
                        }//if match
             }
         }//method city_destination

        void exit_program()
           {
            System.out.println("Executing exit_program");
           }//method exit_program 


                   }//END OF CLASS
```

Comment: Can you please put all the code of this class

Comment: I ADDED ALL CODE FROM THE CLASS AS REQUESTED

Comment: Please could put the code of the main class(contain the main method) and how your *.dat files.

Comment: Would you like the info within them?

Comment: added all the code (including main class/methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,I apologize for the extra late answer.
Here is a first version of your program. You can get, add, modify and delete a flight. And all informations you entered about flights  will be saved on flightsx.dat.

```
public class PhaseIII {


     public static void main(String[] args) {
         array_info data= new array_info();
         int selection;

         selection = data.menu();

         //call start_program & start_program1  
         //DO WHILE LOOP    
         while(selection!=4)
         {
             if (selection == 1)
             {
                 //put call to Modify_flight
                 data.flight_report();
             }
             else if (selection == 2)
             {
                 //put call to Modify_reservation
                 //data.modify_reservation();
             }
             else if (selection == 3)
             {
                 //put call to Report
                 data.report();
             }
             selection =data.menu();
         }//END WHILE LOOP
         //call exit_program   
         data.exit_program();
         System.exit(0);
     }//end main method
}
```

array_info Class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class array_info
{
    int count=-1;
    int rcount=-1;
    String [] flight = new String [100];
    int    [] flight_number = new int [100];
    String [] origin = new String [100];
    String [] destination = new String [100];
    String [] date = new String [100];
    String [] time = new String [100];

    int    [] fl_number = new int [100];
    int    [] reservation_code = new int [100];
    String [] last_name = new String [100];
    String [] first_name = new String [100];
    String [] seat_type = new String [100];
    double [] seat_cost = new double [100];
    {

        count=start_program();
        rcount=start_program1();{
        }
    }

    int menu()
    {
        String mnumber ="";
        int number;
        String output = "ACME AIRLINE SYSTEM" + " \n " + " \n " +
                "1. ADD/MODIFY FLIGHT INFORMATION" + " \n " +
                "2. ADD/MODIFY RESERVATION INFORMATION (Don't Work Yet)" + " \n " +
                "3. REPORT SECTION" + " \n " +
                "4. EXIT AIRLINE SYSTEM" + " \n" + " \n " +
                "Please make your selection  >";
        mnumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, output, " ",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        if(mnumber == null || mnumber.length() == 0 ){
            number = 4;
        }
        else{
            try{
                number=Integer.parseInt(mnumber);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                number = 4;
            }
        }

        return number;
    }//method menu

    int modify_flight()
    {
        String mnumber2;
        int number2;
        String output = "Modify Flight Information Menu" + " \n " + " \n " +
                "1. ADD FLIGHT" + " \n " +
                "2. DELETE FLIGHT" + " \n " +
                "3. MODIFY FLIGHT" + " \n " +
                "4. EXIT THIS MENU" + " \n" + " \n " +
                "Please make your selection  >";
        mnumber2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, output, " ",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        if(mnumber2 == null || mnumber2.length() == 0 ){
            number2 = 4;
        }
        else{
            try{
                number2=Integer.parseInt(mnumber2);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                number2 = 4;
            }
        }
        return number2;    
    }//method modify_flight

    int reportmenu()
    {
        String mnumber3;
        int number3;
        String output = "ACME AIRLINES" + " \n " +
                " 1. All Flight Info" + " \n " +
                " 2. All Reservation Info (Don't Work Yet)" + " \n " +
                " 3. Value of Reservations of a specific type (Don't Work Yet)" + " \n " +
                " 4. All Reservations of a specific flight (Don't Work Yet)" + " \n" + 
                " 5. All Flights from a specific city (Don't Work Yet)" + " \n" +
                " 6. Specific Reservation Information (Don't Work Yet)" + " \n" +
                " 7. Summary of all flights (Don't Work Yet)" + " \n" +
                " 8. All Flights to a specific city (Don't Work Yet)" + " \n" +
                " 9. Exit Report Menu" + " \n" +
                " Please make your selection  >";
        mnumber3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, output, " ",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        if(mnumber3 == null || mnumber3.length() == 0 ){
            number3 = 9;
        }
        else{
            try{
                number3=Integer.parseInt(mnumber3);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                number3 = 9;
            }
        }
        return number3; 
    }//method report_menu

    int start_program()
    {
        String newLine;
        try
        {
            //define a file valuable for Buffered read
            BufferedReader Flights_file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("flightsx.dat"));
            //read lines in file until there are no more lines in the file to read
            while ((newLine = Flights_file.readLine()) != null)
            {
                //there is a "#" between each data item in each line
                StringTokenizer delimiter = new StringTokenizer(newLine,"#");
                count=count+1;
                flight[count] =delimiter.nextToken();
                flight_number[count] = Integer.parseInt(delimiter.nextToken());
                origin[count] =delimiter.nextToken();
                destination[count] =delimiter.nextToken();
                date[count] =delimiter.nextToken();
                time[count] =delimiter.nextToken();
            }//while loop
            Flights_file.close();
        }//end try
        catch (IOException error)
        {
            //there was an error on the file writing
            System.out.println("Error on file read " + error);
        }//error on read
        return count;
    }//end start_program

    int start_program1()
    {
        String newLine;
        try
        {
            //define a file valuable for Buffered read
            BufferedReader Reservation_file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("reservationx.dat"));
            //read lines in file until there are no more lines in the file to read
            while ((newLine = Reservation_file.readLine()) != null)
            {
                //there is a "#" between each data item in each line
                StringTokenizer delimiter = new StringTokenizer(newLine,"#");
                rcount=rcount+1;
                reservation_code[rcount] = Integer.parseInt(delimiter.nextToken());
                fl_number[rcount] = Integer.parseInt(delimiter.nextToken());
                last_name[rcount] =delimiter.nextToken();
                first_name[rcount] =delimiter.nextToken();
                seat_type[rcount] =delimiter.nextToken();
                seat_cost[rcount] = Double.parseDouble(delimiter.nextToken());
            }//while loop
            Reservation_file.close();
        }//end try
        catch (IOException error)
        {
            //there was an error on the file writing
            System.out.println("Error on file read " + error);
        }//error on read
        return rcount;
    }//end start_program1   

    void flight_report()
    {
        // DECLARED VARIABLES]
        int selection2;
        selection2 =modify_flight();
        //DO WHILE LOOP    
        while(selection2!=4)
        {
            if (selection2 == 1)
            {
                //put call to add flight
                add_flight();
            }
            else if (selection2 == 2)
            {
                //put call to delete flight
                delete_flight();
            }
            else if (selection2 == 3)
            {
                //put call to mod flight
                mod_flight();
            }
            selection2 =modify_flight();
        }//END WHILE LOOP
    }//method report

    int add_flight()
    {
        //add new flight information
        String svalue,Output;

        if(count<99){
            count=count+1;
            Output = "Enter the Flight Company";                    //string
            svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                    "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            flight[count] = svalue;

            Output = "Enter the Flight Number";                     //4 digit integer
            svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                    "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            flight_number[count] = Integer.parseInt(svalue);

            Output = "Enter the Flight City Origin";                //string
            svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                    "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            origin[count] = svalue;

            Output = "Enter the Flight City Destination";           //string
            svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                    "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            destination[count] = svalue;

            Output = "Enter the Flight Date";                       //string
            svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                    "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            date[count] = svalue;

            Output = "Enter the Flight Time";                       //string
            svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                    "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            time[count] = svalue;
        }


        return count;
    }//method modify_flight

    void delete_flight()
    {
        String output, svalue;
        int position=0;
        int numFlight = 0;
        output="Enter the Flight Number to delete ";
        svalue=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,output,
                "Input Data",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        if(svalue == null || svalue.length() == 0 ){
            numFlight = -1;
        }
        else{
            try{
                numFlight=Integer.parseInt(svalue);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                numFlight = -1;
            }
        }

        if(count>-1 && numFlight > -1){
            if(count <99 ){
                for(int i=0;i<=count;i++)
                {
                    if(flight_number[i] == numFlight)
                        position =i;
                }
                for(int i=position;i<=count;i++)
                {
                    flight_number[i] = flight_number[i+1];
                    flight[i] = flight[i+1];
                    origin[i] = origin[i+1];
                    destination[i] = destination[i+1];
                    date[i] = date[i+1];
                    time[i] = time[i+1];
                }
            }
            else{
                flight_number[99] = 0;
                flight[99] = "";
                origin[99] = "";
                destination[99] = "";
                date[99] = "";
                time[99] = "";
            }
            count-=1;
        }

    }

    void mod_flight()
    {
        String output,svalue, value;
        int position=-1;
        int modselect;
        int numFlight = 0;
        output="Enter the Flight Number to modify ";
        svalue=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,output,
                "Input Data",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        if(svalue == null || svalue.length() == 0 ){
            numFlight = -1;
        }
        else{
            try{
                numFlight=Integer.parseInt(svalue);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                numFlight = -1;
            }
        }

        if(count >-1 && numFlight > -1){
            for(int i=0;i<=count;++i)
            {
                if(flight_number[i] == numFlight)
                    position =i;
            }

            if(position>-1){

                output="";
                output=output+"1. Modify Flight Company "+"\n";
                output=output+"2. Modify City Origin "+"\n";
                output=output+"3. Modify City Destination "+"\n";
                output=output+"4. Modify Flight Date "+"\n";
                output=output+"5. Modify Flight Time "+"\n";
                output=output+" Please make your selection ";

                value=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,output,
                        "Input Data",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                modselect=Integer.parseInt(value);

                if(modselect ==1)
                {
                    output = "Enter the Flight Company";
                    svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,output,
                            "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                    flight[position] = svalue;

                }
                else if(modselect==2)
                {
                    output = "Enter the Flight City Origin";
                    svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,output,
                            "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                    origin[position] = svalue;
                }
                else if(modselect==3)
                {
                    output = "Enter the Flight City Destination";
                    svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,output,
                            "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

                    destination[position] = svalue;
                }
                else if(modselect==4)
                {
                    output = "Enter the Flight Date";
                    svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,output,
                            "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

                    date[position] = svalue;
                }
                else if(modselect==5)
                {
                    output = "Enter the Flight Time";
                    svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,output,
                            "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

                    time[position] = svalue;
                }

            }
        }
    } 

    /*int modify_reservation()
    {
        //add new flight information
        String svalue,Output;
        rcount=rcount+1;
        Output = "Enter the Reservation Code";                      //4 digit integer
        svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        reservation_code[rcount] = Integer.parseInt(svalue);
        Output = "Enter the Flight Number";                         //4 digit integer
        svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        fl_number[rcount] = Integer.parseInt(svalue);
        Output = "Enter the Last Name";                             //string
        svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        Output = "Enter the First Name";                            //string
        svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        Output = "Enter the Type of Seat";                          //string
        svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        Output = "Enter the Cost of seat";                          //double
        svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        seat_cost[rcount] = Double.parseDouble(svalue);
        return rcount;
    }*///method modify_reservation

    void report()
    {
        // DECLARED VARIABLES]
        int selection3;
        selection3 =reportmenu(); 
        //DO WHILE LOOP    
        while(selection3!=9)
        {
            if (selection3 == 1)
            {
                //put call to All Flight Info
                display_flight();
            }
            else if (selection3 == 2)
            {
                //put call to All Reservation Info
                //display_reservation();
            }
            else if (selection3 == 3)
            {
                //put call to Value of Reservations of a specific type
                //seat_value();
            }
            else if (selection3 == 4)
            {
                //put call to All Reservations on a specific flight
                //print_flight();
            }
            else if (selection3 == 5)
            {
                //put call to All flights from a specific city
                //city_origin();
            }
            else if (selection3 == 6)
            {
                //put call to Specific reservation information 
                //reserve_info();
            }
            else if (selection3 == 7)
            {
                //put call to Summary of all flights 
                all_flights();
            }
            else if (selection3 == 8)
            {
                //put call to All flights to a specific city 
                //city_destination();
            }
            selection3 =reportmenu();
        }//END WHILE LOOP
    }//method report

    void display_flight()
    {
        int i;
        System.out.println("All flight Information:");
        for(i=0;i<=count;++i)
        {
            System.out.println(flight[i]+" "+flight_number[i]+" "+origin[i]+" "+destination[i]+" "+date[i]+" "+time[i]);
        }
    }// method display_flight

    /*void display_reservation()
    {
        int i;
        System.out.println("All Reservations Information:");
        for(i=0;i<=rcount;++i)
        {
            System.out.println(reservation_code[i]+" "+fl_number[i]+" "+last_name[i]+" "+first_name[i]+" "+seat_type[i]+" "+seat_cost[i]);
        }
    }*/// method display_reservation

    /*void seat_value()
    {
        int i;
        double total=0;
        String search_seat = "";
        String output = "Enter the Seat Type you are searching for";
        search_seat = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                output, " ",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        for (i = 0; i <=rcount; ++i) {
            //CHECK IF coach, first, or business
            if(seat_type[i].equals(search_seat))
            {
                total+=seat_cost[i];
                System.out.println(reservation_code[i]+" "+fl_number[i]+" "+last_name[i]+" "+first_name[i]+" "+seat_type[i]+" "+seat_cost[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The total for " +search_seat+ " = " +total);
    }*/// method seat_value

    /*void print_flight()
    {
        int i;
        int total=0;

        String search_flight = "";
        String output = "Enter the Flight Number you are searching for";
        search_flight = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                output, " ",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        for (i = 0; i <=rcount; ++i) {
            //CHECK flight number
            int flight_number = Integer.parseInt(search_flight);
            if(fl_number[i] == flight_number)

            {
                total+=fl_number[i];
                System.out.println(reservation_code[i]+" "+fl_number[i]+" "+last_name[i]+" "+first_name[i]+" "+seat_type[i]+" "+seat_cost[i]);
            }
        }
    }*///method print_flight

    /*void city_origin()
    {
        int i, j;
        int match_count= 0;
        String search_city = "";
        String output = "Enter the City from a particular flight you are searching for";
        search_city = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                output, " ",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        System.out.println(" All flights from "+search_city);
        for (i = 0; i <=count; ++i) {
            if(origin[i].equals(search_city))
            {
                System.out.println(flight[i]+" "+flight_number[i]+" "+origin[i]+" "+destination[i]+" "+date[i]+" "+time[i]);
                match_count=0;
                for (j = 0; j <=rcount; ++j) 
                {
                    if(flight_number[i] == fl_number[j])
                        match_count=match_count+1;
                }//j loop
                System.out.println("The total reservations for " +flight_number[i]+ " = " +match_count);
            }//if match
        }
    }*///method city_origin

    /*void reserve_info()
    {
        int i, j;
        int match_count=0;
        String search_reservation = "";
        String output = "Enter the Reservation Code";
        search_reservation = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                output, " ",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        for (i = 0; i <=rcount; ++i) {
            //CHECK reservation code
            int r_code= Integer.parseInt(search_reservation);
            if(reservation_code[i] == r_code) 
            {
                System.out.println(reservation_code[i]+" "+fl_number[i]+" "+last_name[i]+" "+first_name[i]+" "+seat_type[i]+" "+seat_cost[i]);
                match_count=0;
                for (j = 0; j <=count; ++j)
                {
                    if(fl_number[i] == flight_number[j]);                      //print flight info from that fl_number
                    match_count=match_count+1;
                }//j loop
                System.out.println(flight[j]+" "+flight_number[j]+" "+origin[j]+" "+destination[j]+" "+date[j]+" "+time[j]);
            }//if match
        } 
    }*///method reserve_info

    void all_flights ()
    {
        int i;
        System.out.println("All flight Information:");
        for(i=0;i<=count;++i)
        {
            System.out.println(flight[i]+" "+flight_number[i]+" "+origin[i]+" "+destination[i]+" "+date[i]+" "+time[i]);
        }// NEED TO CATEGORIZE ALL RESERVATIONS (FL_NUMBER) BENEATH EACH FLIGHT (FLIGHT_NUMBER)
    }//method all_flights

    /*void city_destination ()
    {
        int i, j;
        int match_count= 0;
        String search_destination= "";
        String output = "Enter the City to a particular flight you are searching for";
        search_destination= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                output, " ",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        System.out.println(" All flights from "+search_destination);
        for (i = 0; i <=count; ++i) 
        {
            if(destination[i].equals(search_destination))
            {
                System.out.println(flight[i]+" "+flight_number[i]+" "+origin[i]+" "+destination[i]+" "+date[i]+" "+time[i]);
                match_count=0;
                for (j = 0; j <=rcount; ++j) 
                {
                    if(flight_number[i] == fl_number[j])
                        match_count=match_count+1;
                }//j loop
                System.out.println("The total reservations for " +flight_number[i]+ " = " +match_count);
            }//if match
        }
    }//method city_destination*/

    void exit_program()
    {
        String string ;
        FileWriter fw;
        try {
            //System.out.println(count);
            fw = new FileWriter(new File("flightsx.dat"),false);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            //String string = "";
            for(int i =0;i<=count;i++){
                string =flight[i]+"#"+flight_number[i]+"#"+origin[i]+"#"+destination[i]+"#"+date[i]+"#"+time[i]+"\n";
                //System.out.println(string);
                bw.write(string);
            }
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Executing exit_program");
    }//method exit_program 


}//END OF CLASS
```

Let me know if this work, and could you give more explanation about reservation, seat_cost and seat_type

**THE INFO WITHIN FLIGHTSX.DAT:**

```
Southwest#1234#Pittsburgh#Phoenix#04/02/10#10:30am
USAirways#4567#Boston#New York#04/03/10#11:10am
Jet Blue#9876#Pittsburgh#Seattle#04/04/10#1:30pm
Jet Blue#8888#Chicago#Pittsburgh#04/05/10#2:45pm
Southwest#7777#Pittsburgh#Miami#04/06/10#9:35am
Southwest#2892#Las Vegas#New York#04/07/10#8:10pm
USAirways#4444#Pittsburgh#San Francisco#04/08/10#5:55pm
Jet Blue#2222#Atlanta#New York#04/09/10#4:30pm
Southwest#9281#Pittsburgh#Seattle#04/11/10#2:15pm
USAirways#1000#Pittsburgh#Phoenix#04/12/10#3:25pm
```

**THE INFO WITHIN RESERVATIONX.DAT:**

```
1189#1234#Smith#James#coach#299.99#
1190#9876#Jones#Marie#coach#150.00#
1191#2000#Atkins#John#first#789.00#
1192#1000#Gallo#James#first#465.00#
1193#4567#Marion#Kevin#business#300.00#
1194#4444#Johnson#Greg#business#765.99#
1195#8888#Brown#Andrew#first#567.39#
1196#4567#Green#Eric#coach#234.00#
1197#9876#Thomas#Chris#business#1900.99#
1198#7777#Hilling#Cara#first#876.76#
1199#2222#Cole#James#coach#256.99#
1200#9281#Bartko#Grant#business#896.00#
1201#2000#Best#Curtis#first# 543.99#
1202#1000#Campbell#Nicholas#coach#287.00#
1203#4444#Dietz#Merrialyce#coach# 219.00#
1204#9281#Duran#Alexander#business#690.00#
1205#2892#Gurung#Suraj#first# 789.99#
1206#7777#Kumpfmiller#Ryan#first#278.99#
1207#4444#Mccomb#David#coach#451.99#
1208#8888#Mclain#Jaime#coach#199.00#
1209#9876#Mullen#Matthew#coach#189.00#
1210#1234#Nguyen#Tommy#coach#299.00#
1211#1234#Ossler#Aimee#coach#300.00#
1212#7777#Polenavitch#Michael#coach#198.99#
1213#2222#Raymond#Chase#first#908.99#
1214#2222#Rosales#David#coach#216.99#
1215#2892#Schwartz#Dustin#business#987.00#
1216#4444#Short#Samuel#coach#245.99#
1217#8888#Soltis#Josh#coach#178.00#
1218#1234#Webster#Ronald#business#892.00#
1219#1234#Wielock#William#first#589.00#
1220#2892#Bonelli#Andrew#coach#178.00#
1221#4444#Bright#Adam#coach#235.00#
1222#9876#Clymer#Jesse#coach#568.00#
1223#4444#Costello#Michael#coach#200.00#
1224#7777#Currin#Sean#business#908.00#
1225#1000#Farrar#Gary#first#588.00#
1226#1000#Finn#Lynn#business#799.00#
1227#4567#Freise#Brian#coach#254.00#
1228#4567#Huang#Pao-Jen#coach# 199.00#
1229#4567#Kamani#Nelson#coach#150.00#
1230#2000#Loughner#Ryan#coach#175.00#
1231#2000#Menzies#Adam#coach#199.00#
1232#1234#Neupane#Kiran#coach# 135.00#
1233#1234#Nickel#Brandon#first#999.00#
1234#7777#Ropchack#Joseph#first#899.00#
1235#7777#Whitten#Walter#coach#786.99#
1236#4444#Woods#Mary#coach#299.00#
1237#4444#Xing#Zhenli#coach#126.00#
```

Comment: Can I email you the text files?

Comment: Everything looks better, still don't know what you plan on doing with the other reports.

Comment: everything looks great, thank you so much!

but in the main menu, section 2 stops working?
Was working before?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with reserve_info()is that you have an if statement with a semicolon after it, so nothing will happen. You should put braces after it instead.

```
    if(fl_number[i] == flight_number[j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the version 2 of array_info Class. class PhaseIII still the same.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class array_info
{
    int count=-1;
    int rcount=-1;
    String [] flight = new String [100];
    int    [] flight_number = new int [100];
    String [] origin = new String [100];
    String [] destination = new String [100];
    String [] date = new String [100];
    String [] time = new String [100];

    int    [] fl_number = new int [100];
    int    [] reservation_code = new int [100];
    String [] last_name = new String [100];
    String [] first_name = new String [100];
    String [] seat_type = new String [100];
    double [] seat_cost = new double [100];
    {

        count=start_program();
        rcount=start_program1();{
        }
    }

    int menu()
    {
        String mnumber ="";
        int number;
        String output = "ACME AIRLINE SYSTEM" + " \n " + " \n " +
                "1. ADD/MODIFY FLIGHT INFORMATION" + " \n " +
                "2. ADD/MODIFY RESERVATION INFORMATION (Don't Work Yet)" + " \n " +
                "3. REPORT SECTION" + " \n " +
                "4. EXIT AIRLINE SYSTEM" + " \n" + " \n " +
                "Please make your selection  >";
        mnumber = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, output, " ",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        if(mnumber == null || mnumber.length() == 0 ){
            number = 4;
        }
        else{
            try{
                number=Integer.parseInt(mnumber);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                number = 4;
            }
        }

        return number;
    }//method menu

    int modify_flight()
    {
        String mnumber2;
        int number2;
        String output = "Modify Flight Information Menu" + " \n " + " \n " +
                "1. ADD FLIGHT" + " \n " +
                "2. DELETE FLIGHT" + " \n " +
                "3. MODIFY FLIGHT" + " \n " +
                "4. EXIT THIS MENU" + " \n" + " \n " +
                "Please make your selection  >";
        mnumber2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, output, " ",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        if(mnumber2 == null || mnumber2.length() == 0 ){
            number2 = 4;
        }
        else{
            try{
                number2=Integer.parseInt(mnumber2);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                number2 = 4;
            }
        }
        return number2;    
    }//method modify_flight

    int reportmenu()
    {
        String mnumber3;
        int number3;
        String output = "ACME AIRLINES" + " \n " +
                " 1. All Flight Info" + " \n " +
                " 2. All Reservation Info " + " \n " +
                " 3. Value of Reservations of a specific type " + " \n " +
                " 4. All Reservations of a specific flight " + " \n" + 
                " 5. All Flights from a specific city " + " \n" +
                " 6. Specific Reservation Information " + " \n" +
                " 7. Summary of all flights " + " \n" +
                " 8. All Flights to a specific city " + " \n" +
                " 9. Exit Report Menu" + " \n" +
                " Please make your selection  >";
        mnumber3 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, output, " ",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            try{
                number3=Integer.parseInt(mnumber3);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                number3 = 9;
            }
        return number3; 
    }//method report_menu

    int start_program()
    {
        String newLine;
        try
        {
            //define a file valuable for Buffered read
            BufferedReader Flights_file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("flightsx.dat"));
            //read lines in file until there are no more lines in the file to read
            while ((newLine = Flights_file.readLine()) != null)
            {
                //there is a "#" between each data item in each line
                StringTokenizer delimiter = new StringTokenizer(newLine,"#");
                count=count+1;
                flight[count] =delimiter.nextToken();
                flight_number[count] = Integer.parseInt(delimiter.nextToken());
                origin[count] =delimiter.nextToken();
                destination[count] =delimiter.nextToken();
                date[count] =delimiter.nextToken();
                time[count] =delimiter.nextToken();
            }//while loop
            Flights_file.close();
        }//end try
        catch (IOException error)
        {
            //there was an error on the file writing
            System.out.println("Error on file read " + error);
        }//error on read
        return count;
    }//end start_program

    int start_program1()
    {
        String newLine;
        try
        {
            //define a file valuable for Buffered read
            BufferedReader Reservation_file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("reservationx.dat"));
            //read lines in file until there are no more lines in the file to read
            while ((newLine = Reservation_file.readLine()) != null)
            {
                //there is a "#" between each data item in each line
                StringTokenizer delimiter = new StringTokenizer(newLine,"#");
                rcount=rcount+1;
                reservation_code[rcount] = Integer.parseInt(delimiter.nextToken());
                fl_number[rcount] = Integer.parseInt(delimiter.nextToken());
                last_name[rcount] =delimiter.nextToken();
                first_name[rcount] =delimiter.nextToken();
                seat_type[rcount] =delimiter.nextToken();
                seat_cost[rcount] = Double.parseDouble(delimiter.nextToken());
            }//while loop
            Reservation_file.close();
        }//end try
        catch (IOException error)
        {
            //there was an error on the file writing
            System.out.println("Error on file read " + error);
        }//error on read
        return rcount;
    }//end start_program1   

    void flight_report()
    {
        // DECLARED VARIABLES]
        int selection2;
        selection2 =modify_flight();
        //DO WHILE LOOP    
        while(selection2!=4)
        {
            if (selection2 == 1)
            {
                //put call to add flight
                add_flight();
            }
            else if (selection2 == 2)
            {
                //put call to delete flight
                delete_flight();
            }
            else if (selection2 == 3)
            {
                //put call to mod flight
                mod_flight();
            }
            selection2 =modify_flight();
        }//END WHILE LOOP
    }//method report

    int add_flight()
    {
        //add new flight information
        String svalue,Output;

        if(count<99){
            count=count+1;
            Output = "Enter the Flight Company";                    //string
            svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                    "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            flight[count] = svalue;

            Output = "Enter the Flight Number";                     //4 digit integer
            svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                    "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            flight_number[count] = Integer.parseInt(svalue);

            Output = "Enter the Flight City Origin";                //string
            svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                    "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            origin[count] = svalue;

            Output = "Enter the Flight City Destination";           //string
            svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                    "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            destination[count] = svalue;

            Output = "Enter the Flight Date";                       //string
            svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                    "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            date[count] = svalue;

            Output = "Enter the Flight Time";                       //string
            svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                    "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            time[count] = svalue;
        }


        return count;
    }//method modify_flight

    void delete_flight()
    {
        String output, svalue;
        int position=0;
        int numFlight = 0;
        output="Enter the Flight Number to delete ";
        svalue=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,output,
                "Input Data",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        if(svalue == null || svalue.length() == 0 ){
            numFlight = -1;
        }
        else{
            try{
                numFlight=Integer.parseInt(svalue);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                numFlight = -1;
            }
        }

        if(count>-1 && numFlight > -1){
            if(count <99 ){
                for(int i=0;i<=count;i++)
                {
                    if(flight_number[i] == numFlight)
                        position =i;
                }
                for(int i=position;i<=count;i++)
                {
                    flight_number[i] = flight_number[i+1];
                    flight[i] = flight[i+1];
                    origin[i] = origin[i+1];
                    destination[i] = destination[i+1];
                    date[i] = date[i+1];
                    time[i] = time[i+1];
                }
            }
            else{
                flight_number[99] = 0;
                flight[99] = "";
                origin[99] = "";
                destination[99] = "";
                date[99] = "";
                time[99] = "";
            }
            count-=1;
        }

    }

    void mod_flight()
    {
        String output,svalue, value;
        int position=-1;
        int modselect;
        int numFlight = 0;
        output="Enter the Flight Number to modify ";
        svalue=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,output,
                "Input Data",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        if(svalue == null || svalue.length() == 0 ){
            numFlight = -1;
        }
        else{
            try{
                numFlight=Integer.parseInt(svalue);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                numFlight = -1;
            }
        }

        if(count >-1 && numFlight > -1){
            for(int i=0;i<=count;++i)
            {
                if(flight_number[i] == numFlight)
                    position =i;
            }

            if(position>-1){

                output="";
                output=output+"1. Modify Flight Company "+"\n";
                output=output+"2. Modify City Origin "+"\n";
                output=output+"3. Modify City Destination "+"\n";
                output=output+"4. Modify Flight Date "+"\n";
                output=output+"5. Modify Flight Time "+"\n";
                output=output+" Please make your selection ";

                value=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,output,
                        "Input Data",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                modselect=Integer.parseInt(value);

                if(modselect ==1)
                {
                    output = "Enter the Flight Company";
                    svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,output,
                            "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                    flight[position] = svalue;

                }
                else if(modselect==2)
                {
                    output = "Enter the Flight City Origin";
                    svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,output,
                            "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                    origin[position] = svalue;
                }
                else if(modselect==3)
                {
                    output = "Enter the Flight City Destination";
                    svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,output,
                            "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

                    destination[position] = svalue;
                }
                else if(modselect==4)
                {
                    output = "Enter the Flight Date";
                    svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,output,
                            "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

                    date[position] = svalue;
                }
                else if(modselect==5)
                {
                    output = "Enter the Flight Time";
                    svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,output,
                            "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

                    time[position] = svalue;
                }

            }
        }
    } 

    /*int modify_reservation()
    {
        //add new flight information
        String svalue,Output;
        rcount=rcount+1;
        Output = "Enter the Reservation Code";                      //4 digit integer
        svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        reservation_code[rcount] = Integer.parseInt(svalue);
        Output = "Enter the Flight Number";                         //4 digit integer
        svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        fl_number[rcount] = Integer.parseInt(svalue);
        Output = "Enter the Last Name";                             //string
        svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        Output = "Enter the First Name";                            //string
        svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        Output = "Enter the Type of Seat";                          //string
        svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        Output = "Enter the Cost of seat";                          //double
        svalue =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,Output,
                "",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        seat_cost[rcount] = Double.parseDouble(svalue);
        return rcount;
    }*///method modify_reservation

    void report()
    {
        // DECLARED VARIABLES]
        int selection3;
        selection3 =reportmenu(); 
        //DO WHILE LOOP    
        while(selection3!=9)
        {
            if (selection3 == 1)
            {
                //put call to All Flight Info
                display_flight();
            }
            else if (selection3 == 2)
            {
                //put call to All Reservation Info
                display_reservation();
            }
            else if (selection3 == 3)
            {
                //put call to Value of Reservations of a specific type
                seat_value();
            }
            else if (selection3 == 4)
            {
                //put call to All Reservations on a specific flight
                print_flight();
            }
            else if (selection3 == 5)
            {
                //put call to All flights from a specific city
                city_origin();
            }
            else if (selection3 == 6)
            {
                //put call to Specific reservation information 
                reserve_info();
            }
            else if (selection3 == 7)
            {
                //put call to Summary of all flights 
                all_flights();
            }
            else if (selection3 == 8)
            {
                //put call to All flights to a specific city 
                city_destination();
            }
            selection3 =reportmenu();
        }//END WHILE LOOP
    }//method report

    void display_flight()
    {
        int i;
        System.out.println("All flight Information:");
        for(i=0;i<=count;++i)
        {
            System.out.println(flight[i]+" "+flight_number[i]+" "+origin[i]+" "+destination[i]+" "+date[i]+" "+time[i]);
        }
    }// method display_flight

    void display_reservation()
    {
        int i;
        System.out.println("All Reservations Information:");
        for(i=0;i<=rcount;++i)
        {
            System.out.println(reservation_code[i]+" "+fl_number[i]+" "+last_name[i]+" "+first_name[i]+" "+seat_type[i]+" "+seat_cost[i]);
        }
    }// method display_reservation

    void seat_value()
    {

        double total=0;
        String search_seat = "";
        String output = "Enter the Seat Type you are searching for";
        search_seat = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                output, " ",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        for (int i = 0; i <=rcount; ++i) {
            //CHECK IF coach, first, or business
            if(seat_type[i].equals(search_seat))
            {
                total+=seat_cost[i];
                System.out.println(reservation_code[i]+" "+fl_number[i]+" "+last_name[i]+" "+first_name[i]+" "+seat_type[i]+" "+seat_cost[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The total for " +search_seat+ " = " +total);
    }// method seat_value

    void print_flight()
    {
        int total=0;
        int flight_number = -1;
        String search_flight = "";
        String output = "Enter the Flight Number you are searching for";
        search_flight = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                output, " ",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        try {
            flight_number = Integer.parseInt(search_flight);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            flight_number = -1;
        }
        if(flight_number >-1){
            for (int i = 0; i <=rcount; ++i) {
                //CHECK flight number

                if(fl_number[i] == flight_number)

                {
                    total++;
                    System.out.println(reservation_code[i]+" "+fl_number[i]+" "+last_name[i]+" "+first_name[i]+" "+seat_type[i]+" "+seat_cost[i]);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Total of Reservation: "+total);
        }

    }//method print_flight

    void city_origin()
    {
        String search_city = "";
        String output = "Enter the City from a particular flight you are searching for";
        int match_count = 0;
        search_city = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                output, " ",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

        System.out.println(" All flights from "+search_city);
        for (int i = 0; i <=count; ++i) {
            if(origin[i].equals(search_city))
            {
                System.out.println(flight[i]+" "+flight_number[i]+" "+origin[i]+" "+destination[i]+" "+date[i]+" "+time[i]);
                for (int j = 0; j <=rcount; ++j) 
                {
                    if(flight_number[i] == fl_number[j])
                        match_count++;
                }//j loop
                System.out.println("The total reservations for " +flight_number[i]+ " = " +match_count);

            }//if match
        }
    }//method city_origin

    void reserve_info()
    {
        int r_code= -1;
        int flightNum = -1;
        String search_reservation = "";
        String output = "Enter the Reservation Code";

        search_reservation = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                output, " ",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        if(search_reservation == null || search_reservation.length() == 0 ){
            r_code = -1;
        }
        else{
            try{
                r_code=Integer.parseInt(search_reservation);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                r_code = -1;
            }
        }

        if(r_code > -1){
            for (int i = 0; i <=rcount; i++) {
                //CHECK reservation code
                if(reservation_code[i] == r_code) 
                {
                    flightNum = fl_number[i];
                    System.out.println(reservation_code[i]+" "+fl_number[i]+" "+last_name[i]+" "+first_name[i]+" "+seat_type[i]+" "+seat_cost[i]);
                }//if match
            } 
            if(flightNum >-1){
                for (int j = 0; j <=count; j++)
                {
                    if( flight_number[j] == flightNum){
                        //print flight info from that fl_number
                        System.out.println(flight[j]+" "+flight_number[j]+" "+origin[j]+" "+destination[j]+" "+date[j]+" "+time[j]);
                    }   
                }//j loop   
            }
        }

    }//method reserve_info

    void all_flights ()
    {
        int i;
        System.out.println("All flight Information:");
        System.out.println("***********************");
        for(i=0;i<=count;++i)
        {
            System.out.println(flight[i]+" "+flight_number[i]+" "+origin[i]+" "+destination[i]+" "+date[i]+" "+time[i]);
            System.out.println("All Reservation of this Flight("+flight_number[i]+") : ");
            System.out.println("*************************************************************************************");
            for(int j=0;j<=rcount;j++)
            {
                System.out.println(reservation_code[j]+" "+fl_number[j]+" "+last_name[j]+" "+first_name[j]+" "+seat_type[j]+" "+seat_cost[j]);
            }
            System.out.println("*************************************************************************************");
        }
    }//method all_flights

    void city_destination ()
    {
        int match_count= 0;
        String search_destination= "";
        String output = "Enter the City to a particular flight you are searching for";
        search_destination= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                output, " ",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        System.out.println(" All flights To "+search_destination);
        for (int i = 0; i <=count; ++i) 
        {
            if(destination[i].equals(search_destination))
            {
                System.out.println(flight[i]+" "+flight_number[i]+" "+origin[i]+" "+destination[i]+" "+date[i]+" "+time[i]);

                for (int j = 0; j <=rcount; ++j) 
                {
                    if(flight_number[i] == fl_number[j])
                        match_count++;
                }//j loop
                System.out.println("The total reservations for " +flight_number[i]+ " = " +match_count);
            }//if match
        }
    }//method city_destination*/

    void exit_program()
    {
        String string ;
        FileWriter fw = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        try {
            //System.out.println(count);
            fw = new FileWriter(new File("flightsx.dat"),false);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            //String string = "";
            for(int i =0;i<=count;i++){
                string =flight[i]+"#"+flight_number[i]+"#"+origin[i]+"#"+destination[i]+"#"+date[i]+"#"+time[i]+"\n";
                //System.out.println(string);
                bw.write(string);
            }
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Executing exit_program");
    }//method exit_program 
}//END OF CLASS
```